# How to multiply two columns with different two csv file and return result in first csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiple-columns, multiplication

I have two CSV files where first csv file contains Price column and second csv contains quantity i tried to multiply this two columns and save result in new columns with first csv

First.csv

```
Code    Description                                Unit    Price
110101  STATIONARY BICYCLE INDOOR USE               SET    120.25
110106  TREADMILL EXERCISE MACHINE, ELEC. AC110V    SET    950.22
110107  TREADMILL EXERCISE MACHINE, ELEC. AC220V    SET    1000 
110110  EXERCISER ROWING INDOOR USE                 SET    450
110120  BARBELL SET                                 SET    100
```

Second.csv

```
Code     Quantity
110106  210
110107  220
110110  230
110120  240
110122  250
```

And the expected output is

First.csv

```
Code    Description                                 Unit   Price    Total
110101  STATIONARY BICYCLE INDOOR USE               SET    120.25   25252.5
110106  TREADMILL EXERCISE MACHINE, ELEC. AC110V    SET    150.22   33048.4
110107  TREADMILL EXERCISE MACHINE, ELEC. AC220V    SET    100      23000
110110  EXERCISER ROWING INDOOR USE                 SET    40       9600
110120  BARBELL SET                                 SET    100      25000
```

I'm able to read file only

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("QuoteCSV.csv", parse_dates=True)
print(df)
df1=pd.read_csv("itemcode.csv",index_col="Price", parse_dates=True)
print(df1)
```

Updated:

```
   import pandas as pd

    a = pd.read_csv("itemcode.csv")
    b = pd.read_csv("QuoteCSV.csv")
    b = b.dropna(axis=1)
    merged = a.merge(b, on='Code')
    merged.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
    c = pd.read_csv("result.csv")
    c['Total'] = c['Price'] * c['Quantity']
```

But it does not return any rresult

Comment: I'm making an assumption that you want to line these up by the `'Code'` Column.  If I'm right, you expect output is incorrect.

Comment: Why not merge `Quantity` to other dataframe on `Code`, then no need of two dataframe?

Comment: @student i have updated my question and merge two csv into single result.cvs but still it does not return total

Comment: when you call `c.head()`, it does not return anything?

Comment: This for add in csv ---> df.to_csv('new_or_old.csv', mode='a', header=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This one Work

```
df["Total"]=df['Price'].multiply(df1['Quantity'], axis=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: bt it' working. I Just try. check column name also dataframe name also

Comment: it prints correct result in logcat but does not append in csv file

Comment: Multiplication work na yar .. ok  wait I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```
First.assign(
    Total=First.Price * First.Code.map(dict(zip(Second.Code, Second.Quantity))))
```